# Update meta tags in angular universal with external API call

Tags: angular, seo, meta-tags, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I've spent more than 2 months but could not found a clear solution of how to proceed with angular universal.
I've already spent about 6 months in implementing angular universal on a project for which I don't get a much time and now I'm stuck with this issue. Can anyone help me with this as it seems the whole world want to know a solution for Angular SSR.

Here's my code(Meta tag service):

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {commonMetas} from './meta-data.model';

@Injectable()
export class SeoService {
    public commonMetas = commonMetas;
    constructor(public meta: Meta, public title: Title) {}

    setAutomatically (key = 'none') {
        const detail = this.commonMetas[key];
        /** setting defaults */
        this.setTitle(detail.title);
        this.setAuthor();
        this.setDescription(detail.description);
        this.setKeywords(detail.keyword);
    }
    setFromJson(key: {
        title: any,
        description: any,
        image: any,
        keyword: any,
        author: any
    }) {
        key.title = key.title ? key.title : this.commonMetas['none'].title;
        key.description = key.description ? key.description : this.commonMetas['none'].description;

    }
    setTitle(titleToSet = '') {
        this.title.setTitle(titleToSet);
    }
    setAuthor (nameToSet = '') {
        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'author',   content: 'havemybooks.com'});
    }
    setKeywords (keyword = '') {
        this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keyword});
    }
    }
}
```

And my component.ts

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.api.getParticular({id: this.id}).subscribe((response) => {
        this.content = response.blog_data[0];
        this.content.main_image = this.getImage(this.content.main_image);
        this.content.metaCreatedAt = moment(this.content.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.content.displayCreatedAt = moment.utc(new Date(this.content.created_at)).fromNow();
        this.content.name = this.handleName(this.content.name);
        this.seo.setFromJson({
          title: this.content.title,
          image: this.content.main_image,
          description: this.content.blog,
          author: this.content.name,
          keyword: ''
        });
      });
   });
  }
```

Here are some linked StackOverflow questions and GitHub issues:

[Angular universal Server Side Rendering, Meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169175/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-meta-tags)

[Updating meta tags for SEO using angular universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437166/updating-meta-tags-for-seo-using-angular-universal)

[Angular Universal + External API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241355/angular-universal-external-api)

https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta/issues/101

[Angular Universal - OG meta tags not working with child routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704717/angular-universal-og-meta-tags-not-working-with-child-routes)

https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta/issues/118(I tried to get help here from someone who successfully implemented but got no help)

https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/460 (I opened it)

The list goes on I've seen a number of discussions which were never concluded. Anyone who can suggest how to make an API call before rendering in ng-express.

I have implemented SSR and use ngx-meta tag but still, fb crawler shows the default meta tags I used in the head tag.

> UPDATE: I'm able to get the source updated with view source option in
>   chrome but the Facebook and Google crawler show the default meta tags
>   which are there by default. It's very tough to launch my website with
>   it remaining any help is appreciated. @Brandon guided me a lot I spent
>   quite some time on implementing node with Jade and Nunchucks but since
>   angular universal use angular-express by default so I wasn't able to
>   use the above-mentioned render engines.

So is there a way to render meta tags using ng express engine.

Like this `<title>{{meta.title}}</title>...`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Can you please tell how this question is off topic and the questions I linked are not. AFAIK it is allowed to ask the same question if the other one does not have an accepted answer. @Will That's why you can't mark my question a dup. So how is this off topic. I'll edit if need but please let me know

Comment: You're needing to make an API call to get meta tag information when serving your index.html via Angular SSR?

Comment: Yes When I see the page source in an incognito window the meta tags are updated in view-source page but when I try to share to fb it isn't updated @Brandon

Comment: Gotcha. Are you modifying the meta tags after the initial render?

Comment: Yes I'm making an API call in ngOnInit and there I'm updating meta tags so till then init tags in the index.html prevails @Brandon

Comment: and you're needing the opposite of that, correct? Where the API call you're making in the ngOnInit() would happen server-side instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181693/discussion-between-brandon-and-black-mamba).

Comment: Hi, @Brandon I tried implementing nunchucks and ejs but failed to implement as angular universal uses ng-express engine and I wasn't able to find a solution to have both of them implemented.

Comment: You have to use one or the other.

Comment: Here's a Gist with pieces removed of a Universal app using Nunjucks currently in production: https://gist.github.com/alsoicode/42ba0968d2e87a29329d7deac08410ea

Comment: https://github.com/ishan123456789/angular-ssr-nunjucks
Here's the repo I cloned and added nunjucks to but it still fails with SSR but the meta tags are updated @Brandon

Comment: @BlackMamba did you get the solution ?

Comment: @Harsha let me know if you have it

Comment: @BlackMamba no i am also facing the same issue, i looking for solution, if i find some solution i will update here

Comment: @BlackMamba i got one solution i  will post it in answer

Comment: Solution described in this comment on github helped me to solve the issue. It's a bit hacky, but it works => https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta/issues/118#issuecomment-451901245

Comment: I think this link will help you https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/

Comment: @BlackMamba did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't find an easy way to do it but here's a temporary/hacky solution provided by a GitHub user [here](https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta/issues/118#issuecomment-451901245) and I'm quoting his answer directly:

```js
//all imports
enableProdMode();

export const app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql');
const httpRequest = require("request");
// all other consts

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
//all other piece of code in server.ts

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {req, res}, (err, html) => {
    if (html) {
        
        //console.log(html);
        // This is where you get hold of HTML which "is about to be rendered"
    
        // after some conditional checks make a HTTP call
        let url = 'http://....';
        httpRequest.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
                        if(error) {
                            return console.log(error);
                        }
                        const respBody = JSON.parse(body);
                        if(respBody){
                              html = html.replace(/\$TITLE/g, respBody.title);
                              html = html.replace(/\$DESCRIPTION/g, respBody.description);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_META_KEYWORDS/g, respBody.metaKeywords);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_META_DESCRIPTION/g, respBody.metaDescription);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, respBody.ogDescription);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, respBody.ogTitle);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, respBody.img);
                              html = html.replace(/\$OG_SITE/g, respBody.ogSite);
                        }
                        res.send(html);
            });
     }
  }
}
```

And in index.html, create template values as below:

```js
    <title>$TITLE</title>

    <meta name="description" content="$DESCRIPTION"/> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="$OG_META_KEYWORDS" />
    <meta name="metaDescription" content="$OG_META_DESCRIPTION"/> 
    <meta name="metaKeywords" content="$OG_META_KEYWORDS" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="$OG_SITE" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />   
    <meta property="og:image" content="$OG_IMAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented setting title on Angular 2 Universal. It should be done using Renderer, like this:

1.Import Renderer inside of component:

```
import {Renderer } from '@angular/core';
```

2.Add dependency inside of constructor:

```
constructor
    (
        ...
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {}
```

3.Use it now for setting title:

```
renderer.setText(renderer.selectRootElement('title'), value);
```

Comment: In place of 'title' do I need to add page title's text?

Comment: @Rahul No, you should set the title's text instead of the value, the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this looking for same solution.  Using a setTimeout worked for me.  Make sure to refresh cache or use incognito mode or you'll miss seeing the metadata (I made this mistake).  My research suggests that subscribe for API data must be waited upon before SSR renders page so observable must stay open (but I'm not an expert).  https://angular.io/guide/observables.  Also, the only way to make it work is to put the response from subscription right into metaService.  I'll show what I mean in my code.

```
setTimeout( () =>
              this.seo.setFromJson({
              title: this.content.title,
              image: this.content.main_image,
              description: this.content.blog,
              author: this.content.name,
              keyword: ''
            });
    ,0);
```

My code with solution:

```
this.publicFeedService.getPublicProfile(data).subscribe((response:any) => {
        this.memberProfile = response[this.userId];
        setTimeout( () => 
        //Define the meta title using profile data
        this.titleService.setTitle('The best investment ideas from ' + response[this.userId].firstName + ' ' + response[this.userId].lastName), 0);
        setTimeout( () =>         
        //Define the meta tags using the user profile data
        this.metaService.addTags([
          {name: 'keywords', content: 'investing ideas, stock ideas, financial profile'},
          {name: 'description', content: response[this.userId].about},
          {name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow'}
        ]), 0);
```

Comment: I don't think setTimeout awaits the rendering so it shouldn't fix it. Anyways I'll give it a try although it don't seem to help.

Comment: I agree... trust me I've been frustrated about this as well and I'm thinking my answer may fix it by accident.  However, I checked today and Facebook is taking the meta data that was set by the API.

Comment: Which Angular version are you using might be fixed in the latest version. I asked this question back in v6.

Comment: Just following up.  I've gotten multiple pages to work now with API data used to set the meta tags.  I've also been able to do two different API calls and addTags twice and it still updates the page source.  Really curious what issues you may be happening in case I'm missing something

Comment: I haven't updated my angular version after v6 will try in the latest version. I'm waiting for IONIC to release v5 to restructure my app and then use SSR with them. Can you please make a demo github repo for this so I can test quickly.

Answer (score -2):

First Add all required meta tags in index.html file like this

[image: index file]

Then update the meta tags in each required component, use meta.updateTag() as below

[image: component file]

This one worked for me.

I try to create service to update but that not worked, its working only when meta update added in the same component.

Comment: Now press ctrl+u to view page source. You and the crawler won't see the updated meta tags.

Comment: The issue is with API calls they take time to update but crawlers don't wait for response

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -2):

## Solution you can call it!

*A yoda master recipe*

As someone who tried to achieve a SEO friendly angular using SSR and utilities angular has to offer regarding meta tags, I would like to share an idea about this question.


I was so focused on this topic that I failed to see the obvious and how simple it was to solve it!


As you may know HTML would be rendered first, then CSS and only THEN JavaScript.

In addition, index bots mostly care about raw HTML!


There for whether bots should be made to make decisions after they rendered JS
which by the way is not efficient and cost for companies like google and they have their own reasons for doing so, or ...

We can embed single page apps inside specific backend programs compatible of changing the html before sending it to client-side.


Think about it ...

single page application was introduced for a specific new problem and is not opt to be analyzed by only the raw HTML!


So the specific answer to "*Update meta tags in angular universal with external API call*" has already been answered.

How ever, if you would like a real SEO friendly angular app, you must embed them together.

---

> I like doing it in [Spring boot](https://spring.io/) + [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/), If you use any other backend, well you know what to do ...

### Approach

1. Simply build your angular/react/vue projects or in your case project.
   You are not required to build it with angular universal, it's primary idea is to distribute the same index.html page to replicase with folder structure based on your routing with the help of node runners so that you can change the meta tag of each page. I'm sure with enough information you can find a way to embed the app with even that but does it worth it? I leave it up to you.
2. Make strategies for your routes in your backend. Make them all return the index but not before setting proper meta tags and specification you want to apply to it. The client-app it self will do the rest of the work on rendering in the browser.
3. Customize the backend and/or front end for the maximum performance, hell you can do a lot with a devOps as well. Then coffee break.

---

### Tip: with this approach you can have Thymeleaf templates and also manage multiple single page apps together with only routing!

---

> I will provide a simple example as this is only an idea not a tutorial. Feel free to leave comments, I respond shortly afterward.

### Implementation

- **Index.html** let's say I want this meta tag to be dynamic based on a path I consider.

```
...

  <meta th:if="${post}" property="og:site_name" 
th:content="${post} ? ${post.getName()}: 'Your sit name'">

...
```

- **Template Controller** and there goes the paths

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TemplateController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView HomePage() {

        // replace the path you aim for the index.html
        ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("app/index");
        return home;

    }


    @GetMapping("/post/{name}")
    public ModelAndView Post(@PathVariable String name) {

        // replace the path you aim for the index.html
        ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("app/index");
        PostResponse postResponse = new PostResponse();
        postResponse.setName(name);
        home.addObject("post", mock);
        return home;
    }

}
```

- **PostResponse** just a dummy class

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
public class PostResponse {

    private UUID id;
    private Date created;
    private String path;
    private String name;

}
```

---

Now if you simply go to the route page `localhost:port` you can find the meta with *"your site name"*. You go to the page `localhost:port/post/some` name , you'll get the meta with the content, *"some name"*.