# Angular - Prerender command fails and errors

Tags: angular, prerender

I have an angular application setup, nigh on empty. Just recreating a home page example to test general speed in angular.

I have followed the official docs on simply enabling prerendering.

https://angular.io/guide/universal

BUT, when I run the command `npm run prerender` (ng run RegTransfersUI:prerender)

I get:

```
    Prerendering 1 route(s) to D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\browser...ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest3.send (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1518293)
    at Observable2._subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:2901957)
    at Observable2._trySubscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201465)
    at D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201357
    at Object.errorContext (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1407544)
    at Observable2.subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201183)
    at scheduleTask (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:3436471)
    at Observable2._subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:3437074)
    at Observable2._trySubscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201465)
    at D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201357
ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest3.send (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1518293)
    at Observable2._subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:2901957)
    at Observable2._trySubscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201465)
    at D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201357
    at Object.errorContext (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1407544)
    at Observable2.subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201183)
    at scheduleTask (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:3436471)
    at Observable2._subscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:3437074)
    at Observable2._trySubscribe (D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201465)
    at D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\server\main.js:1:1201357
√ Prerendering routes to D:\git\Regtransfers-Core-Ang\dist\RegTransfersUI\browser complete.
- Generating service worker...1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  legend+* -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
× Service worker generation failed.
EPERM: operation not permitted, opendir 'D:\System Volume Information'
```

I cant find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptor:

Do not use `Object.assign()` instead of `request.clone()`. I don't know why but apparently you should not be doing any logic other than using `reqeust.clone()`!

HTTP in `ngOnInit()`:

If you are sending an HTTP request in oninit hook or similar hooks, which will be rendered as soon as component instantiates, like constructor or ngAfterView and ..., use any logic to make sure your code is client side rendered, like `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document)`, do this for all routes you have defined.

Comment: How did you guess that Object.assign() was used?

Comment: @Vega Faced this error many times ...

Comment: i am facing the same error, but i wanted to ask, if we make all http calls to run only on client side then where is the benefit of pre-rendering? i mean i want my home page to load pure static HTML, but if we use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document)` the pre-rendered version will have empty `divs`

Comment: @Kardon63, Well, exactly! prerendering was meant to end some SEO problems and make angular faster but it just end up complicating things. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765453/update-meta-tags-in-angular-universal-with-external-api-call/75542828#75542828) if you are thinking to improve your apps inside corporations